# Getting Error When Using Parameter Variable in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am getting an error when running a query in Access that states that my expression is incorrect or too complex. I am trying to filter a query with a parameter *[Report Date]* on a `DateValue` expression. The query runs without the parameter, unfiltered of course.  It will work if I create a table and write a new query with the parameter but this will need to be run daily and that seems cumbersome.  Syntax below:

```
SELECT tbl_ReturnedEquipment.DateProgrammed, DateValue([tbl_ReturnedEquipment]![DateProgrammed]) AS Expr1, tbl_ReturnedEquipment.CSID, tbl_ReturnedEquipment.NewID
FROM tbl_ReturnedEquipment
WHERE (((DateValue(tbl_ReturnedEquipment!DateProgrammed))=[Report Date]) And ((tbl_ReturnedEquipment.NewID) Is Not Null) And ((tbl_ReturnedEquipment.EquipType)=2));
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with this version of your query? `SELECT rs.DateProgrammed, DateValue(re.DateProgrammed) AS Expr1, re.CSID, re.NewID FROM tbl_ReturnedEquipment AS re WHERE (DateValue(re.DateProgrammed)=CDate([Report Date])) And (re.NewID Is Not Null) And (re.EquipType=2);`

Comment: My SQL is probably not involved.  I did get the same error with your edits.

Comment: What is the value of DateProgrammed before you use the DateValue function?

Comment: Okay, I figured this one out.  Adding "Like" in front of the parameter variable works, e.g. "Like [Report Date]".  Not sure why that is the answer here and it is not required in other queries I have with a parameter variable.